# C# WPF Button "Content" is not displaying

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0.286,0.429" Name="LogGrid">
            <PasswordBox x:Name="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="140,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnSignIn" Content="Sign In" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnSignUp" Content="Sign Up" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Name="MainPart" Width="800" Height="600" Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBox x:Name="Chat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="540" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" AcceptsReturn="True" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <TextBox Name="SendString" Width="740" Height="60" Margin="0, 540, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Button x:Name="SendMsg" Margin="740, 540, 0, 0" Width="60" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Send" />  <-!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        </Grid>
```

The problem is: Button from 2nd Grid, named as "SendMsg" not displays "Content"

Comment: You want the button to say "send", is that what you mean?

Comment: I want to display "Send" string on the button, but it's not displaying :(

Comment: What are you seeing?  An empty button with no content, or no button at all?

Comment: Could you add a more detailed code snippet? What else is in the RenderTransformOrigin and in what control is this loaded? It is difficult to help with just this short snippet.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I see just an empty button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<Button x:Name="SendMsg" Margin="740, 540, 0, 0" Width="60" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Send" />
```

Comment: There is not a "Text" member

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue because I had set a `Height` attribute of `30`, and also a `Padding` attribute of `15`, so my `Content` had been padded right out of the visible space. :)

Comment: Yep. Set padding to 0, folks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure about `Visibility="Hidden"`? I've tested your code (just changed `Visibility="Visible"`) and everything is displayed correctly.

Comment: There is an animation in xaml code, that changes it to "Visible". I've checked it several times, everything works ok, and another TextBox shows text, but only the Button has a trouble with displaying.